# Baraja inglesa : como sacar un escaleras de la misma pinta y calcular puntajes segun el valor de las cartas

Tags: java

Buenas tardes estoy realizando un juego de baraja inglesa en java , el programa ya lo tengo hecho pero estoy con un incoveniente me solicitan lo siguiente:

Incluir la funcionalidad que permita:

- Obtener las figuras en escalera de la misma pinta, es decir, secuencias de cartas que
  tengan la misma pinta. Por ejemplo: 10, J, Q y K de Pica conforman una cuarta de pica.
- Calcular el puntaje del jugador con base en el valor de las cartas que no conforman
  figuras, teniendo en cuenta que las cartas (“Ace”, “Jack”, “Queen”,y “King” valen 10 y el
  resto, el respectivo número del nombre.

Tengo una pista que para escalera puedo ordenar la cartas por el metodo de burbuja para iniciar un secuencia de las cartas pero no como plasmarlo ya validado pero estoy estancado

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
package juegocartas;

import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Carta {

    private int indice;

    //metodo constructor
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public Carta(Random r) {
        //generar el indice de la carta de manera aleatoria
        indice = r.nextInt(52) + 1;
        
        //int sum=0;
        
        
    }
    
    public Pinta getPinta() {
        //devolver la pinta que corresponde al indice de la carta
        if (indice <= 13) {
            return Pinta.TREBOL;
        } else if (indice <= 26) {
            return Pinta.PICA;
        } else if (indice <= 39) {
            return Pinta.CORAZON;
        } else {
            return Pinta.DIAMANTE;
        }
    }
    

    

    public NombreCarta getNombre() {
        int numero = indice % 13;
        if (numero == 0) {
            numero = 13;
        }
        return NombreCarta.values()[numero - 1];
    }
    
       /*public Sumatoria getSumatoria() {
        int suma = indice % 13;
        if (suma == 0) {
            suma = 13;
        }
        return Sumatoria.values()[suma- 1];
    }*/

    public void mostrar(JPanel pnl, int x, int y) {

        //obtener el nombre del archivo de la carta
        String nombreImagen = "/imagenes/CARTA" + String.valueOf(indice) + ".jpg";

        //cargar la imagen
        ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(nombreImagen));

        //Instanciar el objeto JLABEL que mostrará la carta
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(imagen);

        //definir las coordenadas y dimesnion de la imagen
        lbl.setBounds(x, y, imagen.getIconWidth(), imagen.getIconHeight());

        //mostrar la carta en el objeto PANEL de despliegue
        pnl.add(lbl);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

El enunciado del problema deja bastante que desear, entiendo que necesitas generar una escalera a partir de un aleatorio... veamos.

```
int[] generaEscalera( int aleatorio ) {
   int arr[] = new int[ 5 ];
   int rango = 13;
   for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
      if( aleatorio < rango ) {
         int diff = rango - aleatorio; 
         if( diff > 4 ) {
            return creaEscalera( arr, aleatorio, 1 );
         }
         else {
            return creaEscalera( arr, aleatorio, -1 );
         } 
      }
      rango += 13;
   }
   return arr;
}

int[]  creaEscalera( int arr[], int num, int dir ) {
   for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      System.out.print( num + " " + dir + " " );
      arr[ i ] = num;
      num += dir;
   }
   return arr;
}
```

Tal vez no sea muy claro el código, está hecho para no repetir...
El método **generaEscalera**, recibe el número aleatorio, crea el array que va a devolver, y una variable, con la que delimitará los "palos" de la baraja (**rango**).
Dentro del for (que itera un máximo de 4 veces, una por cada "palo"), se comprueba si el aleatorio, es menor que **rango**, de esta manera lo situamos en un determinado "palo", aunque no sepamos cual, si lo es, entra en el if, y asigna a **diff** la resta entre **rango** y **aleatorio**, luego comprueba si esta es mayor que "4", en cuyo caso retorna el valor array instanciado por **creaEscalera** método al que le pasa, el aleatorio, el array, y un entero, que definirá, si la escalera es ascendente o descendente, de acuerdo a la posibilidad o no de que sea ascendente (opción preferida).
Vamos con un ejemplo, que se entenderá mejor que esta ensalada de palabras.

El método **generaEscalera** recibe el número "12".
Entra en el for, y verifica que es menor que **rango** (que en este momento vale "13").
Entra en el if, y resta de **rango** el **aleatorio** quedando **diff** en "1", como es menor que "4", entra en el "else" enviandole a **creaeEscalera** un "-1", que hará que la escalera sea descendente.
Espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro para "desanudar" este código... no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: y en todo este codigo, el palo, donde esta?

Comment: @gbianchi... si lees, puedes deducirlo sin mi ayuda!!!!

Comment: no hay que deducirlo.. ;)

Comment: Porfi, lee la pregunta ;)))).

Comment: ok.. lo voy a dejar aca... tu codigo no devuelve las letras de la baraja (Devuelve numeros)... lo palos dependen del aleatorio (o sea, no se sabe que palo es) ... el return arr de generar escalera es codigo al cual no deberias llegar nunca (porque haces dos return antes). No estas usando la clase carta que usa OP.. no es para votar negativo, pero tampoco me pa que le ayude mucho, basado en lo poco que puso que tiene (y para colmo, OP nunca volvio, es lo que pasa con los ejercicios ;) )

Comment: Ahhhh, se me pasó de comentarte, Java, en su infinita sabiduría, no te permite no poner el último return, yo sé que nunca llego...